# multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

The multi-part identifier "Reporting_Information.Id_Department_Description" could not be bound.

```
Select 
    Basic_Information.Company_No, Basic_Information.Company_Name, Basic_Information.Employee_Code,
    Basic_Information.Surname + ' ' +   Basic_Information.Initials AS Employee_Name,
    Employee_Exceptions.Date,
    Employee_Exceptions.Day ,   Employee_Exceptions.Time ,   Employee_Exceptions.Exception,Employee_Exceptions.Exception_Status,    
    Company_Information.Trading_Or_Other_Name,Company_Information.Address_Line_1, 
    Company_Information.Address_Line_2,Company_Information.Address_Line_3,
    Company_Information.Address_Line_Postal_Code,Company_Information.Period_Start_Date,Department_Descriptions.Short_Description ,      
    Company_Information.Period_End_Date,(CASE Company_Information.Payment_Period
        WHEN 'M' THEN 'Monthly (12)'
        WHEN 'B' THEN 'Bi-Weekly (26)' 
        WHEN 'W' THEN 'Weekly (52)'END) as Payment_Period         
from  Employee_Exceptions     
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Basic_Information  
    ON ( Employee_Exceptions.Id_Basic_Information = Basic_Information.Id_Basic_Information)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Company_Information  
    ON ( Company_Information.Id_Company = Basic_Information.Id_Company)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Department_Descriptions 
    ON (Id_Department_Description = Reporting_Information.Id_Department_Description)
```

Please help

Comment: well, you have no reference to any `Reporting_information` table in your from clauses or in your JOIN clauses.

Comment: Oh Sory man the last clause was suppose to be like this :              LEFT OUTER JOIN Department_Descriptions 
ON (Department_Descriptions.Id_Department_Description = Reporting_Information.Id_Department_Description)   , i was playing around with so i forgot to put it back

Answer (score 1):

Ok Guys i won i just needed to add an extra Join there,
                                                                                      Select Basic_Information.Company_No, Basic_Information.Company_Name ,   Basic_Information.Employee_Code ,
Basic_Information.Surname + ' ' +   Basic_Information.Initials AS Employee_Name ,   Employee_Exceptions.Date ,
Employee_Exceptions.Day ,   Employee_Exceptions.Time ,   Employee_Exceptions.Exception,Employee_Exceptions.Exception_Status,
Company_Information.Trading_Or_Other_Name,Company_Information.Address_Line_1, 
Company_Information.Address_Line_2,Company_Information.Address_Line_3,
Company_Information.Address_Line_Postal_Code,Company_Information.Period_Start_Date,Department_Descriptions.Short_Description ,
Company_Information.Period_End_Date,(CASE Company_Information.Payment_Period
WHEN 'M' THEN 'Monthly (12)'
WHEN 'B' THEN 'Bi-Weekly (26)' 
WHEN 'W' THEN 'Weekly (52)'END) as Payment_Period
from  Employee_Exceptions
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Basic_Information
ON ( Employee_Exceptions.Id_Basic_Information = Basic_Information.Id_Basic_Information)
---Added Join
LEFT OUTER JOIN Company_Information

### ON ( Company_Information.Id_Company = Basic_Information.Id_Company)

LEFT OUTER JOIN Reporting_Information 
ON (Reporting_Information.Id_Basic_Information = Basic_Information.Id_Basic_Information)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Department_Descriptions 
ON (Department_Descriptions.Id_Department_Description = Reporting_Information.Id_Department_Description)